# Is the clique problem polynomial-time solvable still in unit disk graphs allowing different sized disks?

Tags: graphs, np-hard, polynomial-time, clique

[Clark *et al.*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9090358O) proved that the clique problem is polynomial-time solvable in unit disk graphs. Does anyone know if this result holds still if the disks are allowed to be different sizes? Or do such "non-unit disk graphs" in fact constitute all graphs, and thus the clique problem is NP-hard again? (I've been able to draw some of the impossible unit disk graphs found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.08148.pdf) with different sized disks.)

EDIT: as stated in the comments, disk graphs are a strict subset of graphs. In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X00002041) the authors give an example: $K_{3,3}$ is not a disk graph.

Comment: Interesting question, I don't know. But disk graphs do not constitute all graphs.

Comment: As a general tip, a good place to start searching with these questions is to take a look at the ISGCI: [the page on the class of disk graphs](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_414.html) has clique as 'unknown'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is an open problem

In a paper from 2020, [*Maximum Clique in Disk-Like Intersection Graphs*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.02583) by Édouard Bonnet, Nicolas Grelier, and Tillmann Miltzow, the authors note in the abstract that

> (...) The main open question (...) is the complexity of Maximum Clique in disk graphs. It is not known whether this problem is NP-hard.

and proceed to present their results, which can be seen as progress towards proving the problem one way or another.